# audio.play() working within existing function but not as lone function

Tags: javascript, audio

I am trying to make a sound play when a button is clicked. Here is the function that I am trying to use:

```
function sound(){

  var audio = new Audio("button.wav");
  audio.play();

}
```

and then I have this at the bottom of the file:

```
document.getElementById("convert").onclick = function() { sound(); };
```

I know that the code works because if I put the 2 lines of code inside the sound function inside of another function that performs a calculation on the button click, the sound plays. Why is the code only working when added to an existing function, but not as its own?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that by "its own" you are referring to this:

```js
document.getElementById("convert").onclick = sound();
```

In this case, you are assigning the returned value of `sound()` to the `onclick` property of the element. If you want `sound` to be called when the button is clicked, remove the parenthesis:

```js
document.getElementById("convert").onclick = sound;
```

Demo:

```js
function sound(){
  var audio = new Audio("https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-audio/t-rex-roar.mp3");
  audio.play();
}
document.getElementById("convert").onclick = sound;
```

```html
<button id="convert">Play</button>
```

Comment: I added that code to my file and replaced the audio source with the one I'm trying to use and it didn't work. Could it be that my JS file is missing something? I have it setup following a udemy course from 2015 so there could be some issue there.

Comment: @Ceolodolo Does my snippet work for you?

Comment: In my browser it works yeah, but when I put it in my JS file it doesn't play. I'm assuming I can just disregard the button section of the code you put, as that's just referring to the HTML? Even if I keep the audio file as the one you used it wont play.

Comment: @Ceolodolo Where did you place the `script` tag? Make sure it's below the button.

Comment: as the last line of code before the closing body tag

Comment: @Ceolodolo Can you post your full HTML code in a Jsfiddle (or something of the sort)?

Comment: I've never used this site before, but I think that you just need this link, let me know if this isn't what you need. https://jsfiddle.net/belugagem/xph6m19w/

Comment: @Ceolodolo You aren't escaping the `<` and `>` characters. Here's the working version: https://jsfiddle.net/Spectric/eqk5mo4r/

Comment: Are you referring to the two h1 elements? The < > are just for show haha. Assuming they aren't breaking anything.

Comment: @Ceolodolo Yes, I am referring to those. Whether they are for show or not, they are making your HTML invalid.

Comment: Did you make any other changes? I removed them and it didn't fix the sound for me

Comment: @Ceolodolo Try copy and pasting the HTML in the JsfIddle. See if that works.

Comment: If I run just your HTML code, it displays and adds my CSS properly and the button plays the sound. I then added a link to my JS file under the script you wrote, and it makes my JS work but then the sound doesn't work.

Comment: @Ceolodolo Is the path to the audio file correct? Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: If by console you mean the console when I inspect element in my browser, there are no errors. And yeah the path to the audio works because if I put the code to play the sound inside of the function that does the currency conversion on the button click, it plays just fine